# Visual Studio 17.6.2 for Mac not running with breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, safari, breakpoints, visual-studio-mac

Why are breakpoints are not hit when debugging a Blazor WASM project with Safari on Visual Studio on Mac? It works when I use Chrome!

- Visual Studio 17.6.2 (Build 405)
- macOS Ventura 13.4

Comment: Blazor WASM debugging is only implemented currently for Chromium based browsers - Chrome, Firefox and Edge browsers.